# Unity struct fields overlapping with each other and other components

Tags: unity-game-engine

Image showing the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmMYy.png

How can i fix this?

This is the struct code:

```
[Serializable] private struct SpawnableObject
{
    public SpawnableObject(GameObject entity, float lowEndChance, float highEndChance)
    {
        chanceRange = new float[2];
        if(lowEndChance > highEndChance)
        {
            float placeholder;
            placeholder = lowEndChance;
            lowEndChance = highEndChance;
            highEndChance = placeholder;
            Debug.LogWarning("lowEndChance is greater than highEndChance, swapping values.");
        }
        else if(lowEndChance == highEndChance)
        {
            highEndChance += 0.01f;
            Debug.LogWarning("lowEndChance equals highEndChance");
        }
        this.entity = entity;
        isDefault = false;
        chanceRange[0] = lowEndChance; 
        chanceRange[1] = highEndChance;
    }
    public SpawnableObject(GameObject entity, float lowEndChance, float highEndChance, bool isDefault)
    {
        chanceRange = new float[2];
        if(lowEndChance > highEndChance)
        {
            float placeholder;
            placeholder = lowEndChance;
            lowEndChance = highEndChance;
            highEndChance = placeholder;
            Debug.LogWarning("lowEndChance is greater than highEndChance, swapping values.");
        }
        else if(lowEndChance == highEndChance) Debug.LogWarning("lowEndChance equals highEndChance");
        this.entity = entity;
        this.isDefault = isDefault;
        chanceRange[0] = lowEndChance; 
        chanceRange[1] = highEndChance;
    }
    [SerializeField] public GameObject entity;
    [SerializeField] public float[] chanceRange;
    [SerializeField] public bool isDefault;
}
```

Other details:

- The problem persists after restarting unity.
- The problem shows up when an array of the struct is shown in the
  editor (It's ok for an individual one).
- My editor version is 2021.3.3f1 LTS

Extra note for anyone experiencing this problem:
You can click on the 3 dots next to the script/component(when assigned to a GameObject) and click on "Properties...". This will open a menu where the UI is usable.
Not a good fix but at least allows you to use Unity.

Extra note again:
This only seems to happen with the element 0 of the array, so you can skip that buggy one and work starting from element 1, this time on the standard inspector.

Comment: Please show us the code so we can reproduce the issue and suggest a solution.

Comment: Did you write your own custom drawer for this? Does the problem persist after restarting Unity? Your question title says "struct fields" overlap, but your picture is a List - what code do you have that's triggering the issue?

Comment: try adding a blank line and go back into unity and let it recompile.  I have not experienced this, but sometimes fields don't show at all and this usually resolves the issue.

Comment: Added some more information.

Comment: Another possible solution is to add the default constructor.  It is possible unity is having an issue constructing your object since there is no parameter-less constructor.

Comment: The fields do show and work just like normal, it seems to be that the problem is the Unity UI being very confused.